# Why do resistances disappear when studying variations of the voltage Va?

Tags: capacitor, sensor, signal, sinusoidal

I'm trying to solve the question 2.2 of this sensor conditioning exercise. In the solution of the exercise, when trying to find Δ va, the teacher made the resistors R, and the continuous voltage sources E1 and E2 disappear. I think E1 and E2 were simplified because we're only interested by the variations but I do not understand why the resistors disappear.

Could you help me please? We're studying the sensor ADXL50 from Analog Devices here.

Here is the exercise statement:

[image]

[image: the schematic]

Answer (score 0):

The resistors "disappear" because the capacitors do not transmit any DC voltage.
They have a "certain" importance if we lower the frequency (f < 100 kHz).

And so vao = 0 ...
Note that in this AC analysis, the voltage of the sources (V1) is 1 V.

[image]

Answer §2.2 + demodulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply